# Match all paragraphs that are not &nbsp; or in brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a text in the following form:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Email: [client_Email]</p>

<p>Password: [client_password]</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>[client_footer]</p>
```

I want to capture all paragraphs that don't contain only `&nbsp;` or some text between brackets. So in the previous text i'd like to capture:

```
<p>Email: [client_Email]</p> and <p>Password: [client_password]</p>
```

So far, I have the opposite pattern:

```
/<p>(\[.*\]|&nbsp;)/
```

that capture all the paragraphs I don't want...

Here's the code:

```
$phrase = "<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Email: [client_Email]</p>

<p>Password: [client_password]</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>[client_footer]</p>";
preg_match_all('/<p>(\[.*\]|&nbsp;)/', $phrase, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

and the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>&nbsp;
            [1] => <p>&nbsp;
            [2] => [client_footer]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>&nbsp;
            [1] => <p>&nbsp;
            [2] => [client_footer]
        )
)
```

Comment: Don't use regex. xpath can do this much more reliably: `//p[not(contains(text(), '&nbsp;')]`, for one part of the question.

Comment: [this is somewhat relevant and always worth a read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I'd like to use preg_replace to decorate the matching paragraphs. Parsing the HTML source to use xpath would be a bit overkill...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool to do that. But if you really want, here is a way to go:

```
$phrase = "<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Email: [client_Email]</p>

<p>Password: [client_password]</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>[client_footer]</p>";
preg_match_all('/<p>(?!&nbsp;)(?!\[)(.+)/', $phrase, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>Email: [client_Email]</p>
            [1] => <p>Password: [client_password]</p>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Email: [client_Email]</p>
            [1] => Password: [client_password]</p>
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
<p>(?!(?:&nbsp;|\[[^\]]*\])<\/p>).*?<\/p>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cF7eI8/1)

```
$phrase = "<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Email: [client_Email]</p>

<p>Password: [client_password]</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>[client_footer]</p>";
preg_match_all('~<p>(?!(?:&nbsp;|\[[^\]]*\])<\/p>).*?<\/p>~', $phrase, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>Email: [client_Email]</p>
            [1] => <p>Password: [client_password]</p>
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, but only if this is everything you wanna do and expect as far as reading the HTML:

```
<p>(?:(?!\[)[^&]+?|[^&]+?(?<!\]))</p>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ntSR1koN4cJG2vhn)

If you plan on expanding this to read more HTML, consider using a parser in stead.